# Paypal subscription expires after initial payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to integrate a subscription button into one of my pages, but currently getting stuck understanding how the button works.

According to https://www.paypal.com/en/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside, I have to set the following to make a donation per month

```
a3  5.00
p3  1
t3  M
```

Explanation as follows:

```
a3 - amount to billed each recurrence
p3 - number of time periods between each recurrence
t3 - time period (D=days, W=weeks, M=months, Y=years)
```

With the options stated above, a subscription is started, a payment made and shortly after the subscription expires. Paypal's detail page for the subscription says, max cycles is 1.

My assumption is that p3 sets the recurrence to 1. The payment is made, and the subscription expires as max cycles has been hit.

Another theory is, that this auto expire behavior is caused because I verified my paypal account earlier the day (~3h ago). Maybe it needs some time to propagate my new status?

I am wondering why this behavior is caused, and how I am able to set the cycles to a higher amount (permanent?).

My button code is available here http://pastebin.com/vSxVq4tf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, it looks like this is a bug (or missing feature?) in the paypal javascriptbuttons SDK. This behavior is caused since the `src` parameter is missing, that doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.

After adding `src=1` to the button, subscription change from `for one month` to `each month`. I submitted a pull request and currently wait for approval by the paypal folks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic PayPal Standard open source subscription button setup for $10.00 once a month and never ending.

a3 = amount
p3 = number of times to bill ie 1= once a month
 
t3 = (when the billing takes place) ie Monthly

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@youremail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Testing Subscription">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work. I can't find anything wrong with my code - http://pastebin.com/vSxVq4tf Any idea?

Comment: If you are using the basic PayPal button, you need to add the confirmed email address that is affiliated with your PayPal Business account. If you are having errors with your code, you will need to post your code, so that we can see it. The PayPal Button example came directly from a PayPal.com account and it does work if the correct PayPal email is affiliated with it. The button was tested.